# How to use the same fixture to run two different test functions in same script in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

*@pytest.mark.parametrize allows one to define multiple sets of arguments and fixtures at the test function or class.*

It looks like this means that pytest.mark.parametrize can mark a test to run with multiple sets of fixtures? I can find plenty examples of parametrizing arguments, but I can't figure out how to parametrize different test functions using same fixture like pytest.mark.parametrize .

Note I'm trying to do something like this:

```
import pytest
from Test_cases import math_func
from Test_cases import sample

@pytest.mark.parametrize("num1, num2, result",[(2, 3, 5),(2.2, 3.3, 5.5),])

def test_add(num1, num2, result):
    assert math_func.add(num1, num2) == result

@pytest.mark.parametrize("str1, str2, result",[('hello', ' world', 'hello world'),])

def test_string_add(str1, str2, result):
    assert sample.string_add(str1, str2) == result
```

But How to combine two different functions like add and string_add using same mark fixture. i don't want to use mark fixture multiple times ( cause i have lot of test functions to execute ) or is there any other alternative method is there in pytest.

Comment: You can just add the function as an additional parameter, e.g. `parametrize("add_fct, arg1, arg2, result", ...`.

Comment: could you please more specific @MrBeanBremen like how can add parameter additionally to this program Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if you really want to combine these tests. At least with that simple example, it would not make much sense. It is ok to have a bit of duplication in tests, readability is more important here.

That being said, if you still want to do this, you could just add the function you want to test as an extra parameter:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("fct, arg1, arg2, result",
                         [(math_func.add, 2, 3, 5),
                          (math_func.add, 2.2, 3.3, 5.5),
                          (sample.string_add, 'hello', ' world', 'hello world')])
def test_functions(fct, arg1, arg2, result):
    assert fct(arg1, arg2) == result
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and yes i want to combine test cases some time. but i do have a one more doubt what if the functions are different methods one for addition and another one for subtraction i don't want to combine two different function into same function like (test_all_add) but i want to use the single parametrize in pytest is that possible? @MrBeanBremen Like second is a different function is subtraction or do we have any other different methods to use different functions in same parametrize.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your question. You don't want to have addition and subtraction in the same test, but then again you want to? I edited the answer to make clear that it is not specific to addition.

Comment: sorry i'll make it clear here instead of using extra parameter for those two function. is there any other method  is there to combine two different function to using the same parametrize. my final goal is i need to use 3 or 4 different test functions in same script but all functions i want to use only one parametrize like pytest.mark.parametrize how can i use @MrBeanBremen. Thanks :)

Comment: Still don't understand. You will have different parameters and different results for each function, so how do you mean to use the same parametrize for all of them?

Comment: Simply i want rid of the mark parametrize to use all my test function. is there any other alternative method is there @MrBeanBremen

Comment: So, you want to parametrize your functions, but without using `parametrize`? Why?